# Create mean between two julian days for multiple years

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to calculate the mean of the minimum temperature value (minTemp) between April 1st and April 5th for each year of a data set (montbrun).

I have tried simply `filter(julianDays >= 091 & julianDays <= 095)`, but as I was expecting, it doesn't work cause it takes only the first values of the data set that fits to 091-095 values (in julian days).

In other words, my goal is to calculate mean, for every year of the data set between april (Month=4) 1st and 5th (Days= 1 to 5), but in julian days. What I don't know is how to code this when I have multiple years, months and all the julian days in a single year.
Just to clarify, on a normal year, January 1st is 001 and December 31st is 365 in julian days.

Any idea how to code this?

**My Data**

```
montbrun <- structure(list(Year = c(2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005,
2006, 2006,   2006, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2008,
2008, 2008,   2008, 2008), Month = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
4, 4,  4, 4,  4, 4, 4, 4, 4), Day = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1,
2, 3, 4, 5,  1, 2, 3, 4, 5), `Date/Time` = structure(c(1112313600, 
1112400000,  1112486400, 1112572800, 1112659200, 1143849600,
1143936000,   1144022400, 1144108800, 1144195200, 1175385600,
1175472000,  1175558400,  1175644800, 1175731200, 1207008000,
1207094400,  1207180800, 1207267200,  1207353600), class =
c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),  tzone = "UTC"), 
     julianDays = c("091", "092", "093", "094", "095", "091", 
     "092", "093", "094", "095", "091", "092", "093", "094", "095", 
     "092", "093", "094", "095", "096"), minTemp = c(1, -5, -2, 
     -2, -6, 1, -9, 0, -7.5, -5, -7, 0.5, -2.5, -1.5, -10, -8, 
     -17.5, -8, -6.5, -5)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**My Code**

```
example <- montbrun %>%
             group_by(Year) %>%
               filter(Month == 4) %>%
                 filter(Day >= 1 & Day <= 5) %>%
                   summarise(mintemp = mean(minTemp))
```

If someone could help me with that, it would be fantastic !
Thanks !

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of the Julian days. Your sample data frame has `Year`, `Month`, `Day` columns. This is enough to filter rows between April 1 and April 5 and compute the average. Why the complexity about the Julian calendar?

Comment: I only provided a brief sample of my data set. It covers about 20 years in which there are 5 leap years so the releveance of the julian days are for these years. Also in my analysis, I need julian days

Comment: Why does it matter whether it's a leap year or not? The condition `filter(Month == 4, Day >= 1, Day <= 5)` works either way. It might be the case that your question is not 100% clear.